# My app crashes when trying to get a String containing special characters

Tags: objective-c, ios

when i try to display a String, my application crashes:

```
NSLog(@"The start point is: %@",startPt);
```

This is the `startPt` value: `39-49%20Avenue%20d'Ivry,%2075013%20Paris,%20France`. Actually it's returned from the Google Maps web service.

Sometimes, the application didn't crashes, but i got something weird in the Log:

```
The start point is: text/javascript
```

Why i am not able to assign the String `39-49%20Avenue%20d'Ivry,%2075013%20Paris,%20France` to a `NSString` variable?

**EDIT:**

Here is the JSON response parsing:

```
NSString *responseString=[request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict=[responseString JSONValue];

NSArray *resultsArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"results"];

location=[[resultsArray valueForKey:@"formatted_address"] objectAtIndex:0];
            location=[location stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"The location is : %@",location);//39-49%20Avenue%20d'Ivry,%2075013%20Paris,%20France
```

And this is the JSON response returned from the Google maps API:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "39-49",
               "short_name" : "39-49",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Avenue d'Ivry",
               "short_name" : "Avenue d'Ivry",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Quartier de la Gare",
               "short_name" : "Quartier de la Gare",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "13th arrondissement of Paris",
               "short_name" : "13th arrondissement of Paris",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "75",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "75013",
               "short_name" : "75013",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "39-49 Avenue d'Ivry, 75013 Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.82332110,
                  "lng" : 2.36638740
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.82296810,
                  "lng" : 2.36571090
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.82313960,
               "lng" : 2.36602210
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.82449358029150,
                  "lng" : 2.367398130291502
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.82179561970850,
                  "lng" : 2.364700169708498
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Quartier de la Gare",
               "short_name" : "Quartier de la Gare",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "13th arrondissement of Paris",
               "short_name" : "13th arrondissement of Paris",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "75",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Quartier de la Gare, Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.83810700000001,
                  "lng" : 2.3869610
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8189240,
                  "lng" : 2.3556050
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.82807520,
               "lng" : 2.36740680
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.83810700000001,
                  "lng" : 2.3869610
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8189240,
                  "lng" : 2.3556050
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "13th arrondissement of Paris",
               "short_name" : "13th arrondissement of Paris",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "75",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "13th arrondissement of Paris, Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.84496499999999,
                  "lng" : 2.3900530
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8155730,
                  "lng" : 2.3411080
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.83222220,
               "lng" : 2.35555560
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.84496499999999,
                  "lng" : 2.3900530
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8155730,
                  "lng" : 2.3411080
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "75013",
               "short_name" : "75013",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "75",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "75013 Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.84493089999999,
                  "lng" : 2.39026440
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.81587960,
                  "lng" : 2.34112720
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.8307590,
               "lng" : 2.3592040
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.84493089999999,
                  "lng" : 2.39026440
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.81587960,
                  "lng" : 2.34112720
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "75",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.9021450,
                  "lng" : 2.46992090
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8155730,
                  "lng" : 2.2241990
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.8566140,
               "lng" : 2.35222190
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.9021450,
                  "lng" : 2.46992090
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8155730,
                  "lng" : 2.2241990
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "75",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.9021450,
                  "lng" : 2.46992090
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8155730,
                  "lng" : 2.2241990
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.87633370,
               "lng" : 2.34612070
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.9021450,
                  "lng" : 2.46992090
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8155730,
                  "lng" : 2.2241990
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "IdF",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Île-de-France, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.2415040,
                  "lng" : 3.5590070
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.1200810,
                  "lng" : 1.446170
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.84991980,
               "lng" : 2.63704110
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.2415040,
                  "lng" : 3.5590070
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.1200810,
                  "lng" : 1.446170
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.08896180,
                  "lng" : 9.559956999999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 41.34232760,
                  "lng" : -5.1412280
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 46.2276380,
               "lng" : 2.2137490
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.08896180,
                  "lng" : 9.559956999999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 41.34232760,
                  "lng" : -5.1412280
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the surrounding code and circumstance?  What you've stated in the question doesn't crash.  The string in question is percent escaped, %20 being a space.  So you could use [startPt stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsing:NSUTF8StringEncoding] to get rid of them but that probably won't solve the actual cause of your crash problem.

Comment: Most likely the reason for the crash is that the string has been released prematurely: I've seen `NSLog` handle very exotic characters without a problem, so it is rather unlikely that it would choke on a percent sign.

Comment: @Diziet: i will check your suggestion and go back to you :)

Comment: It looks to me that you are not correctly parsing the Google response to the NSString. Can you share the code where you store the google response to the startPT variable ?

Comment: try get the `stringValue` of the object you're outputting, sometimes the object returned from a JSON parser isn't an NSString.

Comment: Ah so you're actually adding the percentage escapes within your code. ;)

Comment: Depends what your doing with it later. If it's just for display you don't need the percentage escapes.  Most of the time if you want to percent escape something it's because your punting it at a web server.

Comment: Malek, where does startPt come from?  Show the line that generates it.

Comment: @Malek -- Again, where does startPt come from??

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possibilities :

---

(1) Why do you assume the string is ASCII? Try a different encoding :

```
location = [location stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Perhaps Google are using a unicode **'** instead of one within the ASCII set? And if you're looking at address data then you can be fairly sure that odd characters are going to get put in there!

---

and (2) *(this one is more unlikely given you have posted the JSON in your question but worth thinking about)*

When you first get `location` you aren't checking that it's actually a string (you aren't checking that 'formatted_address' is an array either!)

What if the JSON returned was this (say there is a bug in the server?) :

```
{ 
    ...
    "formatted_address" : [ { } ]
    ...
}
```

Here, `[[resultsArray valueForKey:@"formatted_address"] objectAtIndex:0];` would work, but it wouldn't return an `NSString`.

Try adding in this kind of check :

```
location=[[resultsArray valueForKey:@"formatted_address"] objectAtIndex:0];
if (NO == [location isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Location wasn't a string (%@) : %@", [location class], location);
} else {
    location=[location stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"The location is : %@",location);//39-49%20Avenue%20d'Ivry,%2075013%20Paris,%20France
}
```

Comment: Hello, It's always goes to the `else` block, so it's a String, i was sure of it. Let's keep in touch

Comment: Hmm, what about trying changing the encoding from ascii to utf8 - does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that startPt isn't an NSString, but rather a `char*`.  If that's the case, the simplest way to create an NSString from it is with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", startPt]`.

Comment: If it's in an NSDictionary it won't be a char*, NSDictionaries only store objects.

Comment: That doesn't address @Diziet's comment at all - if it's from a JSON parse and is in an NSDictionary then we can assume that 'String' means 'NSString'

Comment: He never says where "startPt" comes from, and indications are it's off the network.  If it's a char* that would explain the crash.  Any sort of NSObject would not cause a crash.

Comment: `[responseString JSONValue]` would crash if it's a `char *`, not the `NSLog` - you can't add a `char *` to an `NSDictionary`!

Comment: He said it was crashing on the NSLog of startPt.  Nowhere does he show where startPt is set.  NSLog will only crash if given a bad pointer.